# Greatest value of shortest distance between axis of x and normal to ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, 3d

Show that greatest value of shortest distance between axis of $x$ and a normal to ellipsoid is $$b-c$$
or in other words show that the maximum distance of all the normals to the ellipsoid is $b-c$
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

My attempt :
I have tried to find shortest distance between lines $ \vec{a_{1}}+\vec{b_{1}}t $ 
and $ \vec{a_{2}}+\vec{b_{2}}t $ 
using 
$$ (a1-a2). \frac{\vec{a_{1}}*\vec{a_{2}}}{|\vec{a_{1}}*\vec{a_{2}}|}$$

Assuming that the point at which I am drawing the normal is $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ it comes out to be

$$\gamma\beta \frac{b^2-c^2}{b^2c^2*\sqrt{\frac{\gamma^2}{c^4}+
\frac{\beta^2}{b^4}}}$$

I am not able to go further . Any help/hint would be appreciated

Comment: I have got the same equation but without $p$. Where did it come from?

Comment: you are right , have removed  it cancels out , have removed it . thanks

Comment: The way this is stated is confusing. I assume you are translating from another language. I think you mean "Find the greatest distance from the $x$-axis of all normal lines to the ellipsoid $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1"$$

Comment: A common thing to do in problems like these is to square the distance to eliminate annoying radicals. This now looks like a somewhat messy Lagrange multiplier problem, though there’s probably a more clever way to attack it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes that is what the question meant maximum of ( distance of all the normals of the ellipsoid)

Comment: @amd it is to show that value should be b-c , have added it now , thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the same values of $x,y,z$ which maximize
$$
d(x,y,z)=\frac{|b^2-c^2|}{\sqrt {\dfrac {b^4}{y^2}+\dfrac {c^4}{z^2}}}\tag1
$$subject to the constraint
$$
\dfrac {x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac {y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac {z^2}{c^2}=1,\tag2
$$
 will minimize the value of
$$
\frac {(b^2-c^2)^2}{d^2}=\dfrac {b^4}{y^2}+\dfrac {c^4}{z^2}$$
subject to the same constraint.

The equation $(2)$ together with the other three [Lagrange equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for the latter problem:
$$\begin {align}
\lambda\dfrac {2x}{a^2}&=0;\\
-\dfrac {2b^4}{y^3}+\lambda\dfrac {2y}{b^2}&=0;\\
-\dfrac {2c^4}{z^3}+\lambda\dfrac {2z}{c^2}&=0,\\
\end {align}
$$
can be readily solved with the result:
$$
x=0,\quad y^2=\dfrac{b^3}{b+c},\quad z^2=\dfrac{c^3}{b+c},
\quad\lambda=\dfrac{b^4}{y^2}+\dfrac{c^4}{z^2}=(b+c)^2.
$$
Substituting the last value into $(1)$ one finally obtains:
$$d_\text {max}=|b-c|.
$$